# why did K&R make &&, || logical and &, | bitwise, not the other way around?

Tags: c, language-design

I know that `==` was chosen for equality and `=` for assignment because they thought that people did more assignment than checking for equality---but surely they didn't think that there would be more bit fiddling than boolean logic?

Why not go the other way around, with `&` and `|` being logical operators?

Comment: You "know" that `==` and `=` were chosen that way? Why? What's your source for that? Does that source also talk about `&&` vs `&`?

Comment: I think it kinda make sense to have `==`, `&&`, `||` all logical related. But then we have `<`, `>` vs. `<<`, `>>`.

Comment: I know I've read it somewhere--maybe the preface to the ANSI C book?

Comment: close voters, how is this not constructive? legitimate language design question.

Comment: Dennis Ritchie on the history of `||`, `&&`: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html

Comment: @sarnold post that as an answer?

Comment: @luxun: it's only tangentially related; Dennis doesn't go into detail why they chose the operator names they did. (The main question was about the precedence, not the names.) But I still thought it'd be interesting to all. :)

Comment: @sarnold: That actually more or less explains it -- `&` and `|` predate `&&` and `||`, so they get the shorter operator names.

Comment: @sarnold: I agree with _duskwuff.

Comment: @Als except here, there *is* clearly an answer since dmr talked about it.

Comment: It is not constructive because it's a completely pointless question: it is what it is, and reversing it would have promoted exactly the same question; and because the decision concerned was made over forty years ago by a person who unless I am much mistaken does not frequent this place.

Comment: @luxun: Perhaps, You missed the part of my comment which said *"So I will close vote this as Not Constructive,not because it cannot be answered but because it has little use to anyone in future even if it is answered.Allowing Q's like these in a programming forum is a no for me.*"

Comment: @Als: But that's not correct. When designing a new language, it's always helpful to have information about the decisions beforehand. This tells me that there is no good reason for the decision to be made as it was--but perhaps there might have been (as is the case for other things). Who are you to judge what will be useful to anyone down the road? It certainly was useful for me.

Comment: @luxun: If it is only useful to you and only you then this is not the right platform to ask the Q. *Who I am to judge?*, The SO community gives this right to everyone and anyone who has shown commitment towards the community by earning a certain no of reputation points & contribution towards the community.And I happen to be one.I have an right and authority to cast a close vote on a Q I deem unfit to be in here and I will whether someone(including you) likes me exercising my right or not.

Comment: This is not a fundamentally bad question, it's just not a good fit for a Q&A format because it's more of a discussion than a question. There are two people qualified to answer this factually, and one of them recently passed away. Note, I'm not closing this with a moderator super vote, my vote is the last in five.

Comment: I see that history is not much apreciatted here... Knowing history is important, to try not to repeat past errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [horse's mouth](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html):

> Rapid changes continued after the language had been named, for example the introduction of the `&&` and `||` operators. In BCPL and B, the evaluation of expressions depends on context: within if and other conditional statements that compare an expression's value with zero, these languages place a special interpretation on the and (`&`) and or (`|`) operators. In ordinary contexts, they operate bitwise, but in the B statement
>
> ```
>     if (e1 & e2) ...
> ```
>
> the compiler must evaluate `e1` and if it is non-zero, evaluate `e2`, and if it too is non-zero, elaborate the statement dependent on the if. The requirement descends recursively on `&` and | operators within `e1` and `e2`. The short-circuit semantics of the Boolean operators in such `truth-value' context seemed desirable, but the overloading of the operators was difficult to explain and use. At the suggestion of Alan Snyder, I introduced the `&&` and `||` operators to make the mechanism more explicit.

Remember that C wasn't created in a vacuum; much of its weirdness can be traced to BCPL and B.

Comment: I would accept this, but @sarnold really got the answer first.

Comment: @luxun, please feel free to accept this if you feel Ritchie's description is good enough. John took the time to copy and format the quotation nicely. :)